# Why do I need to specify 'from files'?

Tags: gradle, groovy, jar

I was trying to build a jar out of my first groovy script. My project structure is as follows:

```
- build.gradle
- src\main\groovy\app\Test.groovy
```

My original gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs = ["src/main/groovy"]

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'app.Test')
    }
}
```

From the guides I read, this should create a runnable jar. When I try to run it though I always get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class app.Test
```

I found out now that I need to add these two lines to the jar task:

```
from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
```

The weird thing is that if I replace the groovy script with a Test.java class (same content), I don't need those two extra lines to run the jar.
I couldn't find out why I need them or what exactly they do. Can anyone explain that, or offer a documentation link?

I'm new to SO, please help me with my mistakes.

---

EDIT

The code suggested by tim_yates is translated to test.jar with the following content:
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: app.Test
```

app/Test.class

```
package app;

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class Test implements GroovyObject {
    public Test() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].callStatic(Test.class, "Hi!");
    }
}
```

I execute with the following statement:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

Which results in the error message stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to remember that this jar contains `Groovy` compiled classes. The answer is in your decompiled source that you showed in the beginning. It imports Groovy runtime classes.

If you just run `java -jar test.jar` those classes are not on the classpath.
Either include groovy on the classpath of your command line or use the gradle application plugin to build a `fat` JAR (which is probably better for `runnable` jars) that contain all your application dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName='app.Test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile     'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task uberjar(type: Jar,dependsOn:[':compileJava',':compileGroovy']) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Then build your jar with `gradle uberjar`

Comment: Thanks - makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Test.groovy looks something like:

```
package app

class Test {
    static main(args) {
        println "Hi!"
    }
}
```

Then you only need the following build script:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile     'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'app.Test')
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with those exact file contents (same project setup as I described above), but the error is the same (Could not find or load main class app.Test).

Comment: bet you don't have `package app` at the top of your script

Comment: As I said - I have the exact same file contents, including the package definition.